# Input number in text box display the image

Tags: html, image, css

I have 3000 images in a folder. All named 1000.jpg 1001.jpg and so on.
From 1000 to 3000.
I would like to make a html file and to have a text box and when i input the number (ie, 1000) it will show me the file 1000.jpg.
Also when i would click the file it will hide this.

I need this to properly manage the warehouse and to have the pattern images on my mobile.

Thanks

Comment: is using javascript a viable option to you? Do you have tried anything? show us some code!

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you--

```
<input type="number" id="my-input">
<a href="#">See the Image</a>
<Script>
$("#b").click(function() {

var s=$("#my-input").val()
$("#b").attr("href", s+".jpeg");
}
});
</script>
```

So, what it does is that it takes the value of "#my-input" and appends the value of href attribute to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some thing like this.

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src= folderPath + document.getElementById("inputID").value + ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="imageName"> 
<input type="button" id="view" value="View"/>
<div id="imageDiv">

</div>

<script>
$("#view").on("click", function()
{
var image=$("#imageName").val();
    $("#imageDiv").html("<img src='"+image+".jpg'></img>");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming that this HTML and the images are in the same folder. If the images are in a different folder, change this line:

```
 $("#imageDiv").html("<img src='"+image+".jpg'></img>");
```

For ex: if the images are in a folder called `images`:

```
 $("#imageDiv").html("<img src='images/"+image+".jpg'></img>");
```